# Nextjs 404s on buildManifest across multiple EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, next.js, keystonejs

**Context:** I have a simple Next.js and KeystoneJS app. I've made duplicate deployments on 2 AWS EC2 instances. Each instance also has an Nginx reverse proxy routing port 80 to 3000 (my apps port). The 2 instances are also behind an application load balancer.

**Problem:** When routing to my default url, my application attempts to fetch the `buildManifest` for the nextjs application. This, however, 404s most of the time.

**My Guess:** Because the requests are coming in so close together, my load balancer is routing the second request for the `buildManifest` to the other instance. Since I did a separate `yarn build` on that instance, the `build ids` are different, and therefore it is not fetching the correct build. This request 404s and my site is broken.

**My Question:** Is there a way to ensure that all requests made from instance `A` get routed to instance `A`? Or is there a better way to do my builds on each instance such that their ids are the same? Is this a use case for Docker?

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem with our load balancer and specifying a [custom build id](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/configuring-the-build-id) seems to have fixed it. Here's the [dedicated issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18389) and this is how my `next.config.js` looks like now:

```
const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;

const lastCommitCommand = "git rev-parse HEAD";

module.exports = {
  async generateBuildId() {
    return execSync(lastCommitCommand).toString().trim();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom build directory in your next.config.js file, then remove it and use the default build directory.

Like:

> distDir: "build"

Remove the above line from your next.config.js file.

Credits: https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/issues/467#issuecomment-726227243