# Next.js Error Getting 404 When Fetching JS Resources After Refresh

Tags: next.js

I'm running a Next.js dev server. When I go to page #1, then click a link to page #2, it works great.  (Just to clarify, I'm not using the `as` prop of Next's `<Link>` tag, just the regular old `href`.)

However, if I then refresh page #2, the page itself loads, as do all the images ... but all of the Javascript files fail with a 404:

> http://localhost:3000/page2/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1612664646023
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) 2localhost/:196 GET

> http://localhost:3000/page2/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1612664646023
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) 2localhost/:1 GET

> http://localhost:3000/page2/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1612664646023
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) 7localhost/:196 GET

> http://localhost:3000/page2/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1612664646023
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: What do page #1 and page #2 URLs look like? Are you using `basePath` on your `next.config.json`?

Comment: No `basePath` (but I tried `basePath: ''` and it didn't help.  Page #1 is `index.js`, while page #2 is a dynamic route, ie. `something/somethingElse/[someVar]`.  And again that dynamic route works, *when I click a link from index* ... just not when I refresh after :(

Comment: If there's no `basePath` then why is it trying to load the files from `/page2/_next/...`? Have you tried deleting your `.next/` folder then build and run again?

Comment: I stopped and run `next dev` again. Then the problem solved

Answer (score 7):

Ran into similar problem with inherited code, search a million times this was the top result. My answer for all other frustrated dev out there, check your 'Link' and your 'router.push()' especially if you are using a custom router. The Link and router.push() should be pointing to the server url. You can pass 'as' to mask the url for the browser.

Answer (score 4):

Solved by removing `assetPrefix: "."` from next.config.js file.

This setting makes the assets path based on the current pages instead of the bath path url.

ie:

instead of: "test.com/_next/file.js"

it will be: "test.com/page/_next/file.js"

which obviously does not exist on that.

Answer (score 2):

In our case we fixed it by skipping the next.js router for handling the URL:

```js
  <Link
    onClick={() => {
      const url = '/path/to/url';
      Router.events.emit("routeChangeStart", url);
      window.location.href = url;
    }}
  >
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but with `npm run build` on a React + Next JS template purchased from themeforest. It was because of the Next.js router, `<Link>` set up. This article helped me to fix the issue.

https://www.loudnoises.us/solving-next-static-pages-js-404-not-found/

**The summary of the article is:**

You’ll discover that the issue is that you did not create your  components properly.

Here is what you probably did:

```
<Link
  href={`/articles/${uri}`}
>
  <a>
    Some text
  </a>
</Link>
```

Here is what you should have done:

```
<Link
  href={`/something-else?uri=${uri}`}
  as={`/articles/${uri}`}
>
  <a>
    Some text
  </a>
</Link>
```

For larger applications, add this to your **next.config.js** file

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  distDir: "_next",
  generateBuildId: async () => {
    if (process.env.BUILD_ID) {
      return process.env.BUILD_ID;
    } else {
      return `${new Date().getTime()}`;
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Troubleshooting -**

1. stop your node process / server / pm2
   Test if you can still access the website.
2. if you run htop - you can filter for node - and you may be surprised to see a lingering node process running on same port.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm update
```

has resolved my issue;

this error comes from node module not updated version to package.json updated version mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to add the following line in `next.config.js` file according to NextJS doc:

```
module.exports {
  assetPrefix: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/about/" : undefined,
}
```

Assuming `/about/` is your replacement page or a domain your trying to add as a prefix.

ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix

Comment: There's not just one "correct solution": this same issue can have many causes, even if this was the "correct" one for you.  As a result, every solution people can provide might help someone, so this *is* a great answer ... I just am not sure about using that word "Correct".

Comment: that's fair, updated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove assetPrefix: "." from next.config.js file, and works!

Check here in which case you should use the assetPrefix: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix

Answer (score 0):

If you use **generateBuildId** in your **next.config.js**, make sure that it bumped to a new version. It may cause the issue on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the cloud provider which had caching mechanism which resulted in caching the previous build's js assets. cleared the cloud's cache and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue where some assets (CSS, JS, build manifest, etc.) would randomly 404 when I refreshed, and realized that the reason was because my environment was using load balancers.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63817674/nextjs-404s-on-buildmanifest-across-multiple-ec2-instances) and added that to the **generateBuildId** option to my `next.config.js` as noted [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/generateBuildId).

Basically, you need to create a random unique ID for each build that gets returned from the function you pass to **generateBuildId** so that the the static assets only serve from one node instead of multiple.

In the `next.config.js`, I passed a function that read the Git SHA from an environment variable (i.e. I added a GIT_SHA value to process.env) that I set during a build step:

```js
generateBuildId: () => {
  return process.env.GIT_SHA || '';
}
```

How you get and set that SHA is entirely up to you. The resources I linked off to above have some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

verify if you don't have two same folder named app or you don't have app and src folder in the root

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a ec2 instance and my problem was that two node process was running in the same port. The first that should be the main, a pm2 node, wasn't actually the process that my website was. So i stoped him to be sure, with `pm2 stop PID`. After that, server in port 3000 was still runing because was not anymore pm2, but a node process. You have to stop the node process and start pm2 again after those steps below:

In the processes, search for node to see if its keep runing

```
ps aux | grep node
```

Get that pid that will be showed

```
lsof -i :3000
```

Then kill that process

```
kill -9 PID
```

At the end, you should be able to start your pm2 again.

```
pm2 list | pm2 start PID
```

Thank you [johndpope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284895/johndpope), you confirmed my problem.