# next js https://my_website_address/_next/static/chunks/webpack-332dbc5711e5ed.js net:: err aborted 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, plesk

My website https://gracious-mclean.45-194-27-50.plesk.page/

[image]

Here is the error. I couldn't figure it out.

In vercel everythings fine. (Im using plesk, VDS server)

emirpreview.vercel.app

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it with removing `assetPrefix: "."` from `next.config.js`.

Comment: Hey but i dont have assetPrefix on next.config.js ): i dont know what should i do...

Comment: @questiontoansw check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66084031/next-js-error-getting-404-when-fetching-js-resources-after-refresh) out

Comment: I dont use any Link either too... And that page didn't work too. I'm trying to figure it out for many hours. ):

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why but i turned the reactStrictMode to false in next.config.js, then the error disappeared.